# Will the new technologies in 12.10 be backported to 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I was wondering if the new dash animations and web apps and other new technologies be backported to 12.04?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, otherwise, what's the point of an LTS release? Stable Ubuntu releases are supposed to change at little as possible, hence they only get critical bug and security fixes. New and potentially unstable features are limited to tesing and non-LTS releases.

Comment: In addition to bug and security fixes in LTS versions, there are also updates to support more/new hardware.

Comment: If memory serves, there are some exceptions being made for some things in 12.10...

Comment: Quite so. New hardware support is added, and kernel versions are backported from newer releases, but I am pretty sure the new Unity 6.6 will qualify.

Answer (score 2):

mikewhatever is right.

However if the LTS warranty is not a criteria for you there is various "backport" repositories.

using those void the LTS warranty like mikewhatever pointed out.

Backports are mainly maintained by volunteers and you can have no updates from one day to another and security is not granted.

The LTS is more like the Debian way : Secure and stable operating system. This means that you'll not have latest features (witch are exactly the opposite).

backports can easily be found for the kernel, multimedia packages, xorg, various famous programs (gimp, libreoffice, ...).

Using them is always at your own risks.